# How to use Error Concealment in JSVM

Tags: h.264

I have one video file that lost some frame and I want to using error concealment to recover this video file? What is command that I need if I use JSVM 9.18

Thank all

Answer (score 0):

In the JSVM manual:

```
    H264AVCDecoderLibTestStatic str rec [-ec ec_value]
```

where ec_value equals 1 (all macroblocks are assumed to be coded using BLSkip), 2 (frame copy) or 3 (all macroblocks are assumed to be coded in direct mode).

I use JSVM 9.19 and unfortunately, ec is not working...